# How to pass user id

Tags: rest, get, jwt

Suppose super admin wants to see another sub admin's details
my current method is GET -- domain/api/user/get_by_id/{id}
I'm using JWT also.
is my method correct?? Is there any other method where I don't put the id directly in URL

my current method is GET -- domain/api/user/get_by_id/{id}

Answer (score 0):

So, answering your questions one by one,

1. > is my method correct??

If you are using RESt Web services as you have added that tag, then no, this should not be the url. I would suggest you to read upon REST web services a little as the url should look somewhat like this.

```
GET -- domain/api/user/{id}
```

Also the id you put in url is a public one  and not the one of your database. So a entry in the database should look like:

```
Id | Username | userId (it is public)
1  | debabrata| r1398fh9238yhas89
```

So to call the url **r1398fh9238yhas89** will be passed and not *1*.

2. > Is there any other method where I don't put the id directly in URL

You could encode the id in base64, jwt style or some kind of other encryption or as earlier stated just send a public ID which doesn't mean anything for your database.